How do I package a WinUI app as exe setup file or something that includes all dlls while installation?
I am facing while packaging a WinUI app. As by using the publish and package option directly from VS Studio creates the msix file but when I install that file in other computers, I realized that all libraries(dll) for libraries that were installed using Nuget aren't present in the installation. But when I copy the files and dlls from debugging results to other computer's installation directory. Then its starts working.
Can anyone explain what to do so as to package the file into a single file which will include all dlls to put in installation directory.
Packaging Results from Direct options
Can anyone tell how to create a single installation msix package or even better an exe setup file like we have with other softwares

Have you performed all the steps in the documentation?

No, I just used the package and publish method. I will try to do it according to documentation.

For Winui3 project, here is a workaround. If you need to include DLL in MSIX package form Visual Studio, you need to add the dll file to the WinUI3 project, right click on the project -> Add existing item -> add your dll file -> set the Content property to true.

I am using EasyModbusTCP library to communicate to a hardware through my software to take sensor's data. So when I do simple Package and publish and try to install the msix  file on ther computer the app does not work, it opens up but cannot comminuicate with the hardware. But when I copy and paste the files in debug folder to installation directory of the on other computer then it works. So what is the problem I don't understand??

The packaging is usually done according to the configuration in release mode. Have you tested it in release mode? How did you import EasyModbusTCP? Is it through NuGet?

Yeah through Nuget

https://i.sstatic.net/65TVI3UB.png  I tested it and found that the EasyModbus.dll is in the package. Could you please use the MSIX packaging tool to check it?

If you want to create a windows installer, use WiX Toolset.
In case you want a single output, publish the output to a single file.
Single-file deployment
